# Having Trouble Pointing Existing Rails 3.2.9 Application to Database Created with postgres.app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.2, postgres.app

I currently have a Rails 3.2.9 application that is using PostgreSQL databases that were recreated using PgAdmin when I upgraded my Mac Mini Server to Mountain Lion.  The databases were created as version 9.2.1 unbeknownst to me.  I suppose the version of PgAdmin I used created them with that version number.  I only had the Postgres version 9.1.4 that came with the upgrade to Mountain Lion.  I submitted another question about how to get the version of psql to match the version of my database files as this was causing a problem with implementing queue_classic to run background jobs.  At this point I have not received any responses.  I continued to look and learned about postgres.app.  The current version is running PostgreSQL 9.2.2.

I have copied the data from the current database into CSV files.  I have also used the psql terminal in the postgres.app and created new databases that I want to use in my Rails application.  I decided to change the definition of the development & test databases in config/database.yml to make sure I don't mess up the production database until I have thoroughly tested this.  To make sure I know the different I created the databases with different names to make sure that I would be able to know for sure that my Rails application is pointing to the databases created with postgres.app.

I changed my path in ,bashrc as stated on the postgres.app website.  When I do which psql it correctly points to the postgres.app version 9.2.2.  I changed config/database/yml for development to the following according to what the website for postgres.app said to do.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: newname_devl
```

When I ran my Rails app using localhost:3000 as I normally do, the application is pointing to the original database.  I was expecting an error since I had not done a rake db:migrate to rebuild all my tables in the new databases.

Somehow I need to be able to get my PostgreSQL database versions to match the version of PostgreSQL but I do not know where to go from here.  I will continue looking.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 12/31/2012 5:50 am CST GMT-6**

I tried the command below.  This is one I had tried before.  I got the error (username masked) listed under the command.

```
psql -h localhost
psql: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

I created the role "username" and attempted the command again.  I got the following error.

```
psql: FATAL:  database "username" does not exist
```

I decided to try the command below.  I got the error listed under the command.

```
psql -h localhost -U _postgres
psql: FATAL:  database "_postgres" does not exist
```

Database _postgres does not exist; database postgres does.

Answer (score 1):

If you've updated database.yml to the correct name, I'm not sure how it would be accessing the wrong database.  What happens when you change the database name in database.yml to "foobar123" or some name that you're positive doesn't exist in either the old or new Postgres?

Comment: The name I created in postgres.app was different than the current database.  I confirmed that I saved database.yml before checking.  I expected an error when I tried to pull up the new database because no tables existed.  The version of psql was from postgres.app.  My app ignored what I had done.  I think I will rebuild the databases I have within the psql that came installed on my Mac Mini Server so they are the same version as psql.  I am learning about the psql terminal.  How would I log into psql as a superuser to create databases? I have only used it to maintain tables.

Comment: "psql -h localhost" should log you in as superuser. Or "psql -h localhost yourdbname" to acces the database.

Comment: I just updated the description with my results.  It looks like psql is installed in such a way that you can only maintain existing databases, not create them.  I had hoped to be able to try and implement gem queue_classic for background jobs which takes advantage of PostgeSQL but this version conflict prevents me from using it.

Comment: I decided to do a little more searching.  I just found out about the EXPORT command where I can get the databases where I need them.  I will try to use the gem again.  Thanks so much for your help.  If it does not work I will try something else for background jobs.